# Magento success page - echo item details plus custom attribute

Tags: php, magento

One of our affiliates require us to assign and pass a commission value on the success page that is specific to each product.
Currently the code below passes the sku, price and quantity in a pixel we fire...

```
<?php echo $this->getItems();?>
```

I need to do the same but add a custom product attribute to the end of the string, for example...

```
skutest1 : 2.99 : 1 : 15 | skutest2 : 3.99 : 2 : 10 |
```

(The 15 and 10 at the end of each item is the custom attribute)

Here is what I have so far....

```
<?php
$order_items = $order->getAllItems();
foreach($order_items as $item) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
    echo $product->getSku();
    echo ':';
    echo $product->getPrice();
    echo ':';
    echo $product->getQty();
    echo ':';
    echo $product->getAttributeText('affiliate_comission');
    echo '|';
}
 ?>
```

$product->getQty();   and  $product->getAttributeText dont pass any values which is where I am getting stuck!

P.S I know commission is spelt incorrectly in the code but I can't change the attribute code now :(

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution!

Below is the fixed commented code...

```
<?php
$order_items = $order->getAllItems();

foreach($order_items as $item) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
    echo $product->getSku();
    echo ':';
    echo round($product->getPrice(), 2); //Modified to round to 2 decimal places
    echo ':';
    echo round($item->getQtyOrdered());  //Changed $product->getQty(); to $item->getQtyOrdered(), also added round to make a whole number 
    echo ':';
    echo $product->getData('affiliate_comission'); //changed getAttributeText to getData
    echo '|';
}
 ?>
```